# Hide Trackbacks/Pingbaks if none exists

Tags: comments

I managed to get my comments numbered and then to separate the comments from the pingbacks and trackbacks. The only problem I have now is that I don't want to show the title of this section (where the trackbacks/pingbacks are) unless there are any.

This is the code I'm using in comments.php:

```
<div class="pingback"><h3>Trackbacks/Pingbacks:</h3>
        <?php   
        wp_list_comments(array(
          'callback'=>'list_pings',
          'style'=>'ol',
          'type'=>'pings',
        ));
        ?> 
</div>
```

And this is the code from functions.php:

```
<?php
function list_pings($comment, $args, $depth) {
$GLOBALS['comment'] = $comment;
?>
<li id="comment-<?php comment_ID(); ?>"><?php comment_author_link(); ?>
<?php } ?>
<?php
add_filter('get_comments_number', 'comment_count', 0);
function comment_count( $count ) {
if ( ! is_admin() ) {
global $id;
$comments_by_type = &separate_comments(get_comments('status=approve&post_id=' . $id));
return count($comments_by_type['comment']);
} else {
return $count;
}
}
?>
```

I think I should do an `if/else` statement but I can't figure out where to start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am using a helper function for that.

### `functions.php`

```
/**
 * Count amount of pingbacks + trackbacks for a post.
 *
 * @param int $post_id Post ID for comment query. Default is current post.
 * @return int
 */
function t5_count_pings( $post_id = NULL )
{
    $pings    = 0;
    $comments = FALSE;

    if ( NULL !== $post_id )
    {
        $comments = get_comments(
            array (
                'post_id' => $post_id, # Note: post_ID will not work!
                'status'  => 'approve'
            )
        );
    }
    elseif ( ! empty ( $GLOBALS['wp_query']->comments ) )
    {
        $comments = $GLOBALS['wp_query']->comments;
    }

    if ( ! $comments )
        return 0;

    foreach ( $comments as $c )
        if ( in_array ( $c->comment_type, array ( 'pingback', 'trackback' ) ) )
            $pings += 1;

    return $pings;
}
```

### `comments.php`

```
if ( $num = t5_count_pings() )
{
?>
<h2 id="pingbacks"><?php
    printf( _n( 'One pingback', '%d pingbacks', $num, 't5_theme' ), $num );
?></h2>
<ol class="pinglist ■ sans-font">
<?php
wp_list_comments(
    array (
        'type'     => 'pings',
        'style'    => 'ul',
        'callback' => 't5_list_pings_callback'
    )
);
?></ol>
<?php
}
```

Now, if there are no pingbacks and no trackbacks `$num` = 0, and the markup for the list will not be printed.

You can use the function with a post ID to count the number of pings for another post than the current page like this: `t5_count_pings( 12345 )`.